# exporting drupal database from devlopement box to drupal database (new from install ) in cpanel - duplicate data

Tags: mysql, drupal-7, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I am new to phpMyAdmin, and cPanel, I have developed a site in my local box, and now I need to transfer the site into cpanel in the server where the site will be there in test mode.

I have installed drupal in cpanel successfully, and now I want to take my drupal database from my local box to the database in Cpanel .

so the export file I generated, includes all the insert statements for some of the tables that already have those data in cpanel, so obviously I get the duplicate primary key error.

how can I import drupal database data (my local box -development) into the new drupal database( set up when installed drupal in cpanel) without dealing with duplicate data which is for the default tables/data

I am using phpMyAdmin in both my local (dev) box and server side
I appreciate any one 's help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a new empty DB on the host, import your dev db, then change the db name in the settings.php file to point to the new DB.

Comment: thanks,I did this and created a new schema while keeping the other schema that was used when installing drupal. changed setting.php to this new schema. Now the problem is when I import to new schema, it doesn't bring all tables(like semaphore table) and I got an error table semaphore does not exist when I navigate to the site. I searched and realized that drupal thinks that the database already exist so it does not bring all tables when I import to new schema. people suggesting installing drupal again. is there a way not to install again and be able to import my database fully ?

Comment: error I get is same as what mentioned here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591260/drupal-installation-pdoexception

Comment: Not to sure about that error, but another alternative would but to zip up the dev site and extract it on the host vs. making a new install.

Comment: I figured the issue was my export file not having those tables, I didn't understand why those tables did not come in export file in first place, but the 2nd time I got another export, they were there and were able to generate all tables in host.my issue was not related to what all other talking about in the link I sent previously.To make things easier, I think I might have been able to import the database into the existing one without creating new schema(with Add/drop table option when I did export from my local box)? what do you think ?deleting the existing one after testing with new schema